# React.js -- Multiline Comment Syntax Error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So in my render function I have this code:

```
<NavBar
                title={AppHelper.formatText(this.state.productTitle || '')}
                leftIcon={'arrow'}
                leftScene={'pop'}
                leftAction={false}
               {*/
                rightIsText={false}
                rightIcon={'search'}
                rightScene={'productSearch'}
                rightAction={false}
                */}
                white={false}
            />
```

But for some reason, I get a syntax error `Unexpected token, expected ...` on the last line.

Can anyone offer some insight as to why this comment isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For properties of a component I believe you have to do it like this:

```
// rightIsText={false}
// rightIcon={'search'}
// rightScene={'productSearch'}
// rightAction={false}
```

Comment: This seemed to work. I was under the impression that when rendering components multiline comments had to be within curly brackets to be run as javascript.

Comment: @R.Jacobs You cannot insert a property name as JS (only their value). The following should work`<div title={a.b /* something \nsomething\nsdomerthing */} ></div>` (\n is a newline for my code sample)

Comment: In your render you would use curly brackets if you're commenting out the components themselves, not their properties: `{/* <View /><View /> */}`